# PHP's Date function for Day light saving

Tags: php, date, dst

Is PHP's native `date()` function return Time according to `DST`?

Let's consider example here. Timezone set in `php.ini` is `America/New_York`.If we consider `Tue, 20 Dec 2011 20:57:45 +0000` then is it display date `Tue, 20 Dec 2011 15:57:45 -0500` or `-0400` for DST?

Comment: What are you asking? You've given us a UTC date and printed it in two timezones. America/New_York respects DST.

Comment: Don't use date() if you want to handle daylight savings; use DateTime objects and then your DateTimeZone object has a getTransitions() method that will even tell you when the changes take place

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: I recommend using `DateTime` (and `DateTimeZone`) objects too.

Comment: Basically project is already implemented using `date` function and changes to be taken out so I ask this

Comment: @MikeB I am asking for `date()` consider `DST` or not ?

Comment: @DevalShah Yes? You know this because you compared date() output with America/New_York with vs Etc/GMT-4. Change your computers date and suddenly America/New_York matches up with Etc/GMT-5. The manual page on date() goes over all this in great detail.

Comment: @MikeB: `Etc/GMT-x` is reverse `GMT-x`. So `Etc/GMT-4` is `GMT+4` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If your timezone is correctly set (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) then it will account for DST.